# Anyone knows where I can find a simple FEniCS code where I can understand basic implantation?

Tags: finite-element, fenics

I found this one, but does not work: http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~hron/warsaw_2014/pl2014_lecture5.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [FEniCS book](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/83776282/fenics-book-2011-10-27-final.pdf) or the [FEniCS Tutorial](https://fenicsproject.org/pub/tutorial/pdf/fenics-tutorial-vol1.pdf).